# Changing Word table columns before a page break in C#

Tags: ms-word, interop

I have a 6-column table (ABCABC). As soon as the left columns (ABC) are filled and a page break occurs, the right three columns (ABC) should be written further up. The problem is, I don't get the page break. I don't know when the table breaks to the new page.

[image]

Edit: I tried to solve it only in MS Word (as end user). but there is no satisfactory solution. now i try to solve it programmatically.  But somehow I get the page breaks too late. Only when a row was created on the new page.
is there the possibility to address a cell in a table also on the basis of the page? Cell one in the table on page one?

```
int pageNumber = GetPageNumberOfRange(table.Cell(r, 1).Range);

// Assign cells if page breaks

if (pageNumber % 2 == 0)
{
    cellInColumnA = table.Cell(r, 4);
    cellInColumnB = table.Cell(r, 5);
    cellInColumnC = table.Cell(r, 6);
}
else
{
    cellInColumnA = table.Cell(r, 1);
    cellInColumnB = table.Cell(r, 2);
    cellInColumnC = table.Cell(r, 3);
}

r++;



private static int GetPageNumberOfRange(Word.Range range)
{
    return (int)range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber];
}
```

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the required end result, originally. Not sure I understand what you're asking, now. How is the code in the question not working? I would expect `WdInformation` to return the page number of the specified `Range` (cell).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to describe the problem better.

Comment: There is no event triggered when Word generates a new page or breaks something to a new page. I don't understand what it is you want with "is there the possibility to address a cell in a table also on the basis of the page? Cell one in the table on page one?" Are you asking how to access only the cells that have broken to another page? Or a cell on the starting page for the table? The latter is easy enough; the former could be tricky...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to access both types of cells. cells that wrap to a new page and cells that, for example, are first on a page. is that possible?

Comment: And in what way is `GetPageNumberOfRange` not working? I would expect it to return the page number?